# Display List from Top Level Site to SubSite in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I've requirement to display the top level site (Made with modern communication site template ) library to it's sub sites. Whenever there is a change in top level library it should reflect in sub sites library as well.

I got the below reference and tried, but my webpart not showing while creating new app though the template available in Webpart gallery.

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/08/display-list-from-top-level-site-subsite-in-sharepoint.html

I also tried to enable the SharePoint Content Query web part (or Content Search Web Part) by enabling publishing feature turned ON, but getting unexpected error while activating the feature.

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should consider avoid creating subsites, instead just link sites using hub sites.

To get one site content items show on another site I suggest you use **Highlighted Content** web part on the modern page.

[image: Highlight content settings]

Comment: Hi Bnerd.. Thanks for quick reply. I need to show the replica of my parent document library. Using highlighted content webpart i am not able to select the list or libraries using filer and, and this webpart only shows the frequently used docs or forms only.

Comment: You should be able to use a managed property to filter documents from specific doc library and sorting.... You can always just link to the list/library on the main site instead of displaying content on every site? Otherwise, maybe create a custom webpart displaying content you want which you can use on any site.